# Why QWebEngineView doesn't show my image?

Tags: python, html, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

```py
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
...
...
q = QWebEngineView()
q.setHtml('''<img border="0" height="200" src="E:/img.png" style="display: block; text-align: left;" width="600">''')
...
...
```

above is the only code I deal with webengineview.
I want to show image within the webengineview, but it doesn't work, the outcome is a broken image icon.

when I open the html text with chrome browser, it actually works.

and then I set the img "src" attribute to be some other web image, it still works.

and it works if I set the src as "data:image/png;base64,xxxx" format.

I cannot figure out what happened

Comment: it's access to file system, because i load the html text from the file, then pass it to webengineview. the demo code is the reduced code with the same problem

Comment: You need to use the `baseUrl` argument of [setHtml](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html#setHtml). And note that it must be a *file://* url that includes a trailing slash: i.e. `baseUrl=QtCore.QUrl('file:///E:/'))`. If you do that, it will also be possible to use relative paths in the html. This applies to all external resources - not just images.

Comment: @ekhumoro thanks for your advice. instead of setHtml(), I use setUrl() now, and it works

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the issue might be connected to wrong path you specified. I assume you use Windows, and then the correct `src` would be `E:\img.png` (notice the slash has opposite direction).

Comment: I checked your solution but in vain.  and I set the src to be file:///E:/img.png or file:\\\E:\img.png, it doesn't work either.